# how can i make a garage door opener run in one direction only

Tags: wiring

I am using an old garage door opener for a school project but the motor must only run in one direction. How do I get the motor to run in one direction only?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You'll have to figure out how to hack the motor controller board, which is probably beyond our "Home Improvement" remit.

Comment: Basically remove one of the two up/down adjuster contacts.

Comment: @Kris that depends on how old this motor/controller is.  There may not be any mechanical contacts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all garage door controllers built since roughly 1990 automatically stop , then reverse direction when you hit the control button.  (Yes, I used to have a 1986-era opener where you could stop the door with the button but not reverse it. )

Since the control logic, aside from limit switches and strain sensors, is almost certainly hardwired into the control electronics board, you are going to have some difficulty.

What I'd do is remove the electric motor entirely from the electronics. Make sure you know what voltage drives the motor, and wire an appropriate supply directly to the motor (with on/off switch, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mechanical solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esVq6jfTigM

[image]

The idler (purple and yellow) switches sides depending on the rotation of the input, orange.   You can take power off either the blue or the green.